# Rust imports in wasm-pack code causing JS error

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-pack, rust-wasm, rust-bindgen

I'm getting a JS error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" error: module is not an object or function`

When I view the wasm file in the Chrome dev tools, I see import statements like this, at the top:

```
(module
  (func $blst_hash_to_g2 (;0;) (import "env" "blst_hash_to_g2") (param i32 i32 i32 i32 i32 i32 i32))
  (func $blst_sign_pk2_in_g1 (;1;) (import "env" "blst_sign_pk2_in_g1") (param i32 i32 i32 i32))
  (func $blst_scalar_from_bendian (;2;) (import "env" "blst_scalar_from_bendian") (param i32 i32))
  (func $blst_sk_check (;3;) (import "env" "blst_sk_check") (param i32) (result i32))
```

What is causing these import statements?  How can I remove or fix them?  I can see they are part of the `blst` Rust package, which is included by the `blsttc` package.  The `blst` package uses bindgen to generate FFI bindings to blst.h, so maybe that has something to do with it?

This [Github repo](https://github.com/LIT-Protocol/threshold_crypto_ui) has the code.  I am building using `wasm-pack build --target=web`

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is that `env` should be, but isn't being generated by `wasm-pack`. This typically happens for me if the build artifacts get corrupted, which can happen if I abort the build process during code generation. The solution is then to run `cargo clean` to remove the corrupted build artifacts and build the whole project again from scratch.

Comment: Since you have a C dependency, are you building with `CC=emcc wasm-pack build --target=web` using emscripten's latest sdk? I've successfully built your github repo using that command.

Comment: @glennsl Cargo clean did not work, but thank you

Comment: @MathieuRene it does not build for me, even with the latest emscripten and CC=emcc.  The build process is dying on the blst package with the error "error: failed to build archive: section too large"

Comment: emcc 2.0.25 rustc 1.53.0 wasm-pack 0.10.0 on ubuntu20.04 here, what are your os/component versions?

Comment: Hey @MathieuRene, I switched to Ubuntu 20.04 with latest everything and it works great now.  I was on mac os 10.15.7.   Thanks for trying it on Ubuntu and helping me realize that something about my mac's setup is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by switching to Ubuntu 20.04 with latest everything and it works great now.  I was on mac os 10.15.7.